# Sqlalchemy representation for custom postgres range type

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have the need for a custom range type. I am trying to represent an hourly range. For each day of the week a range (datetime.time, datetime.time) rather than separate TIME columns, I would like to have access to Postgres/sqlalchemy range operators if possible.

I'm looking for something like TSRANGE but hours instead of the normal (datetime.datetime, datetime.datetime)

In postgres itself this works wonderfully. For example.

```
create type timerange as range (subtype = time);

create table schedule 
(
  id integer not null primary key,
  time_range timerange
);

insert into schedule 
values
(1, timerange(time '08:00', time '10:00', '[]')),
(2, timerange(time '10:00', time '12:00', '[]'));

select *
from schedule
where time_range @> time '09:00'
```

So here is the question. How do I represent this custom type I have created in Postgres in SQLAlchemy? Subclass TSRANGE, TypeDecorator on TIME, or possibly create a new SQLALchemy UserDefinedType. I am not quite sure which way to go. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to use custom range types you [need to dig a bit deeper](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ranges.RangeOperators):

> When instantiating models that use these column types, you should pass whatever data type is expected by the DBAPI driver you’re using for the column type. For `psycopg2` these are `NumericRange`, `DateRange`, `DateTimeRange` and `DateTimeTZRange` **or the class you’ve registered with `register_range()`**.

In other words you have to both register your custom range type with your DBAPI – usually `psycopg2` – and create the SQLAlchemy types to match the registered types. [`register_range()`](http://pythonhosted.org/psycopg2/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.register_range) takes the name of the PostgreSQL `range` type, a (strict) subclass of [`Range`](http://pythonhosted.org/psycopg2/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.Range) and a connection/cursor used to fetch the oids. It can register the new range type either globally, or locally to the given connection or cursor:

```
In [2]: import psycopg2.extras
```

The value type you should use when creating instances of models:

```
In [3]: class TimeRange(psycopg2.extras.Range):
   ...:     pass
   ...:
```

Use [`raw_connection()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.raw_connection) in SQLAlchemy to fetch a proxy to the underlying `psycopg2` connection. Registering should perhaps be done in a setup function in an actual implementation:

```
In [4]: conn = engine.raw_connection()

In [5]: cur = conn.cursor()

In [6]: psycopg2.extras.register_range('timerange', TimeRange, cur, globally=True)
Out[6]: <psycopg2._range.RangeCaster at 0x7f1c980dbe80>

In [7]: cur.close()

In [8]: conn.close()
```

Next create the SQLAlchemy range type to match the registered `TimeRange`. A [`TypeDecorator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator) is ill suited, since you're not using an existing type. [`UserDefinedType`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.UserDefinedType) should be the base of all entirely new types. For range operators include the [`RangeOperators`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ranges.RangeOperators) mixin:

> It is used by all the range types provided in the postgres dialect and can likely be used for any range types you create yourself.

The rest is pretty much copied directly from [the predefined range types](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/ranges.py):

```
In [11]: from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

In [13]: from sqlalchemy import types as sqltypes

In [14]: class TIMERANGE(postgresql.ranges.RangeOperators, sqltypes.UserDefinedType):
    ...:     def get_col_spec(self, **kw):
    ...:         return 'timerange'
```

This is only required for reflection.

```
In [16]: postgresql.base.ischema_names['timerange'] = TIMERANGE
```

And then just create your tables and use as you would normally:

```
In [17]: schedule = Table('schedule', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

In [18]: schedule
Out[18]: Table('schedule', MetaData(bind=Engine(postgresql:///sopython)), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<schedule>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('time_range', TIMERANGE(), table=<schedule>), schema=None)

In [19]: session.query(schedule).all()
Out[19]: 
[(1, TimeRange(datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(10, 0), '[]')),
 (2, TimeRange(datetime.time(10, 0), datetime.time(12, 0), '[]'))]

In [20]: session.query(schedule).\
    ...:     filter(schedule.c.time_range.contains(time(9, 0))).\
    ...:     all()
2017-04-11 10:01:23,864 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT schedule.id AS schedule_id, schedule.time_range AS schedule_time_range 
FROM schedule 
WHERE schedule.time_range @> %(time_range_1)s
2017-04-11 10:01:23,864 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'time_range_1': datetime.time(9, 0)}
Out[20]: [(1, TimeRange(datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(10, 0), '[]'))]
```

Comment: Beautiful, this was exactly what I was after. Great information and really useful for defining custom ranges. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you also show how a model would be defined under the class-based approach, ie, `class Schedule(Base): ...`?